# How can I write a filename parameter to a variable and pass it as an argument?

Tags: bash

It's about bash and quoting within a variable. The following function logs its arguments.

```
printArguments () {
    for ((i = 1; i <= $#; i++)) do
        # i = 1, 2, …
        # ${!i} -> indirect expansion => $1, $2, …
        echo -n "\$$i=»${!i}«  "
#       echo -n "\$1 =»$1«  "
#       echo -n "\$2 =»$2«  "
    done
    echo ""
}
```

This call gives out 2 arguments:

```
printArguments foo 'file name'   # $1=»foo«  $2=»file name«
```

This also works if I write the "file name" into a variable `a`. The file name will be a parameter, hence i write it in a variable `a`. The output is the same:

```
a='file name'
printArguments foo "$a"          # $1=»foo«  $2=»file name«
```

If I write all arguments into a variable `b`, an argumentString, it doesn't work anymore:

```
b='foo "$a"'
printArguments $b                # $1=»foo«  $2=»"$a"«
```

Here are my further attempts. The "file name" breaks into 2 arguments (Insert `printArguments $b` for the `…`):

```
b="foo \"$a\""; …                # $1=»foo«  $2=»"file«  $3=»name"«  
b="foo "$a""; …                  # $1=»foo«  $2=»file«  $3=»name«
b="foo '$a'"; …                  # $1=»foo«  $2=»'file«  $3=»name'«  
q="'"; …                         # $1=»foo«  $2=»'file«  $3=»name'«  
v=a; …                           # $1=»foo«  $2=»"${!v}"«  
v=a; …                           # $1=»foo«  $2=»"file«  $3=»name"«  
b="foo $(printf '%q' "$a")"; …   # $1=»foo«  $2=»file\«  $3=»name«  
b="foo $(printf '"%q"' "$a")"; … # $1=»foo«  $2=»"file\«  $3=»name"«
```

How can I write the two arguments – one of them is itself a parameter and contains blanks – into one variable `b`?

I need this in a script to build different variants before a command should work with it. Since the command gets many more arguments, I don't want to call the command again for each variant individually.

Edit: **Solutions** from this thread:

Solutions with an array:

```
b=("foo" "$a");         printArguments "${b[@]}" # $1=»foo«  $2=»file name«
b=("foo" "$a");         printArguments ${b[@]}   # $1=»foo«  $2=»file«  $3=»name«

declare -p b # prints the contents of the array b => declare -a b=([0]="foo" [1]="file name")
```

The empty array `()` is not a zero argument, like `""`:

```
b=("foo" "$a"); printArguments a "${b[@]}"    c # $1=»a«  $2=»foo«  $3=»file name«  $4=»c«
b=();           printArguments a "${b[@]}"    c # $1=»a«  $2=»c«
                printArguments a "${b[@]-""}" c # $1=»a«  $2=»«  $3=»c« # mix the array expansion with another parameter expansion
                printArguments a ""           c # $1=»a«  $2=»«  $3=»c«
```

`eval` can create serious problems if the evaluated string cannot be controlled. For example, if as user input an arbitrary command can be passed to `eval`, then this, e.g. `rm …`, will be called by `eval` and will e.g. delete `…`.

```
b='foo "$a"';           eval "printArguments $b" # $1=»foo«  $2=»file name«
b='foo "$a"';           eval printArguments $b   # $1=»foo«  $2=»file name«
```

With `bash -c` also you'll run into the same pitfalls as eval if you're not careful with it.

```
export -f printArguments
export a='file name'
b='foo "$a"';        bash -c "printArguments $b" # $1=»foo«  $2=»file name«
```

- You can only use single quotes within the command or argument strings.
- Only exported environment variables will be available to the command.
  Without `` => bash: Line 1: printArguments: Command not found.

Comment: Fast answer is "use an array". `b=( "foo" "$a" ) ; printArguments "${b[@]}"`

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you asked it to do, its splitting the arguments you pass into the function on spaces.   In one case you passed 'foo "file name"' in the other you passed 'foo "file name"' after expansion.. which is the same thing. I'm not sure why you are expecting it to output something different in case `b` then case `a`.

Comment: @UpAndAdam: I tried to solve my problem. Therefore, I have shared my attempts.

Comment: @tjm3772: Thank you! Arrays solve my problem completely :-)

Comment: I have described above under "Edit: Solutions" the three solutions from this thread:

 - Arrays (`()`) work great.

 - `eval` is potentially dangerous.

 - `bash -c` does not work yet. Does anyone have an idea how I can get it to work?

Comment: To get `bash -c` to work you'd need to export the function first (look at `export -f`) but also you'll run into the same pitfalls as `eval` if you're not careful with it.

Comment: If you want to use the array but also get the same behavior as providing an empty argument then you can mix the array expansion with another parameter expansion like so - `printArguments a "${b[@]-""}" c`

Comment: I have edit and include this above :-) and i have update the `printArguments`-function

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is relevant.